# Bison error message generation with line numbers

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to generate proper compile errors in a Flex/Bison setup. I added code to the lexer to keep track of line and character numbers and to add those to each token matched, as follows:

```
struct yystype {
  std::string s;
  DefLocation def;
  union {
    ...
  }
};
```

This is my yystype, with "s" being used for any string-y type and the union containing any pointer type (for some more type safety). Only one of those two is ever used though.

```
#define TOKEN yylval.s = yytext; yylval.def = DefLocation {yyfilename, yytokenoffs, (size_t)yylineno }

%option yylineno

out                         { TOKEN; return OUT; }
in                          { TOKEN; return IN; }
```

This basically sets the text & forwards a DefLocation (simple struct) that says where the definition is.

Now my problem is, Bison exposes whichever field of the struct my rule or token is defined as:

```
%token <s> IN OUT
%type <e> expression13 expression12
```

I can't find out how to get to the def location though. Is there a way to access the entire yylval for a given part of the rule, to extract the def locations? Alternative could be to include them in each token, but that would be very annoying & ugly.

Comment: Usually errors are detected pretty quickly during a parse.  So accessing the line number as a global variable is ok.

Comment: I want to have the line numbers available until code generation time so if I very late on in the process detect a suboptimal construction that you could fix in code I can tell you where it is. Also, this is more generically usable; in the language I'm targeting code generation is very late on and can find errors late on. Remember GCC's linker errors without line numbers? This'll prevent that.

Comment: Then every production type used by the parser needs to include a line number.